# Module not found: javafx.web

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I wanted to create a WebView with Javafx, and I added `requires javafx.web;` to my module-info.jar, but IntelliJ say: "Module not found: javafx.web".

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.graphics;
```

works without any problem.
What can I do?

Comment: I assume you mean module-info.java not .jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you also added a dependency to javafx-web in Maven/Gradle or added the corresponding jar file to your build?

Answer (score 0):

**Was facing same problem in Gradle build system, Fixed by putting dependency under javafx tag inside build.gradle file.**

```
 javafx {
     version = '17.0.6'
     modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web']

}
```